# How to check if kubernetes job is successful or failure using client go library

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

There are lot of fields out there in the library but it basically talks about job finished or not, but how to check if a job is finished and successful or job is finished and failure

```
if con.Type == v1.JobComplete && con.Status == corev1.ConditionTrue && job.Status.Succeeded > 0 {
    fmt.Printf("Job: %v Completed Successfully: %v\n", name, con)
    break
} else if con.Type == v1.JobFailed && con.Status == corev1.ConditionTrue {
    if job.Status.Active == 0 && job.Status.Succeeded == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Job: %v Failed: %v\n", name, con)
        break
    }
}
```

This is how I am checking now, I am not completely sure this is correct

Comment: What did you try? What exactly is wrong with checking the status of the job pod?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: did the above code, is checking `(c.Type == batchv1.JobComplete || c.Type == batchv1.JobFailed) && c.Status == v1.ConditionTrue` sufficient to say if a job is finished and for success do a  jobComplete check and for failure doa  jobFailed check, is this sufficient

Answer (score 4):

Similar to `Bharath`s answer except it handles the race condition where this function is called after the job is created but before the job pod is active.

```
func getJobStatus(jobName string) error {
    // k8sClient := initialize k8s client

    job, err := k8sClient.BatchV1().Jobs(h.namespace).Get(jobName, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if job.Status.Active == 0 && job.Status.Succeeded == 0 && job.Status.Failed == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s hasn't started yet", job.Name)
    }

    if job.Status.Active > 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s is still running", job.Name)
    }

    if job.Status.Succeeded > 0 {
        return nil // Job ran successfully
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("%s has failed with error", job.Name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just the Active, Succeeded and Failed variables to know the status of the job.

Example:

```
    batchClient := kubernetesapi.BatchV1()
    jobClient := batchClient.Jobs(NameSpace)


    job, _ := jobClient.Get(jobName, metav1.GetOptions{})

    if job.Status.Active > 0 {
    return "Job is still running"

    } else {
      if job.Status.Succeeded > 0 {
       return "Job Successful"
       } 
       return "Job failed"
    }
```

This should take care of any number of retries to the job if you are using **backOffLimit** as more than 1.

Comment: This has a race condition if the job is provisioning a pod, it may not go into active state before status is fetched. IE: the container may stay in containerCreating for a brief period while an image is pulled down, or a volume is created/attached

Comment: @iainlbc what is your proposed fix to this race?